# Blinking text and changing color

Tags: visual-studio, text, colors

I would like to blink my text and change the text with color while blinking. But what I saw from the other sites is to use textcolor, but when I want to use textcolor, it does not have in my Visual Studio. So how can I blink my text?

Comment: Questions (and answers) regaring blinking text should be fairly easy to find already, either here on stackoverflow or elsewhere on the internet. If your issue is with Visual Studio, address this with a proper explanation. What is the problem and what have you tried to do so far?